# Linq in C# - Change type

Tags: c#, linq

Why (and how) change type of 'b' b 'System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.List'

```
List<int> a = new List<int>{ 45, 78, 45, 12, 4, 78, 54 };  
var b = a.Select (n => n +12).Where (n => n>50); //Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<int>

b = b.ToList ();  // System.Collections.Generic.List<int>
```

Why change type of b? Its possible to change type in C#? for example, Is it possible to create 'String' and change it to 'int' for 'char'? of course, not. but Why changed type of this code?

Comment: Well... Why did you write that code? What was your intention?

Comment: I don't get it. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @atornblad Nothing )) I'm just learning C#

Comment: you are doing it. what is the question ?

Comment: @Dr.Chameleon that's good but what are you trying to achieve? Selman22 is correct, you have already used the `.ToList()`

Comment: You have answered the how, altought you cannot reassign the result to b.  And as to why, b does not evaluate until such a time as you access the result.  By Calling b.ToList() you evaluate the expression held in b and assign the result to a variable.

Comment: you'd use the enumerable if you you can stick to enumerating the contents, and convert it to a list if you need the list features

Answer (score 2):

`.Where<T>()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.  `Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<T>` is the concrete class that `Enumerable.Where` uses to implement that interface.  You shouldn't reference it in your code since it's an implementation detail and subject to change.

`.ToList()` takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and creates a concrete `List<T>`.  IT does not just "change the type" as you mention in your question - it creates a *new* object.  *How* it does it is another implementation detail that you shouldn't need to worry about.

You can browse the .NET Reference Source to look at the implementation of [`Where`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/e73922753675387a.html) and [`ToList`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/e276d6892241255b.html)

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are after this

```
  var b = a.Where(n => n > 50).Select(n => new
            {
                a = n+12
            }).ToList();
```